# How to make srcset recognise that an image will not be displayed at full size on small displays?

Tags: html, css, image, srcset

I have images that are displayed at 100% of the viewport width, up to a maximum width of 960 CSS pixels. I am using `srcset` to deliver a version of each image that is 960px wide to regular displays, and a version that is 1920px wide to displays that have a high pixel density.

The issue is that when it comes to viewports narrower than 960px, the images get reduced in size to fit. This results in narrow viewports getting served images at higher resolutions than they require because `srcset` does not realise these images aren't going to be displayed at 960px wide.

I wish to avoid server-side scripting, but lightweight (no JQuery) client-side scripting is okay if necessary. A pure HTML/CSS solution would be preferred.

**Edit:**

As suggested, I have whipped together an example. You might be best copying this to a local file:

```
<picture>
    <source type="image/webp" srcset="https://dummyimage.com/960x540/000/fff, https://dummyimage.com/1920x1080/000/fff 2x">
    <img style="width: 100%; max-width: 960px; height: auto;" src="https://dummyimage.com/960x540/000/fff" width="960" height="540" alt="">
</picture>
```

To see what I mean, try the following. Adjust these figures appropriately if you have a high PPI display and do a proper refresh before every step if using Chrome with the cache disabled from the developer tools (Ctrl+F5 will not reset which image gets loaded!). Firefox appears to automatically switch based on zoom level:

1. Start at 100% zoom. The 960px image should load.
2. Start at 200% zoom. The 1920px image should load.
3. Start at 200% zoom with a viewport as narrow as you dare. The 1920px still loads!

I am aware that CSS media queries can be used to set different rules for different viewport sizes, but there must surely be a better way that lets the browser decide and doesn't rely on setting explicit rules for viewport ranges.

**Another edit:**

Doing the following using `sizes` and `w` looked promising:

```
<picture>
    <source type="image/webp" sizes="(min-width: 960px) 960px, 100vw" srcset="https://dummyimage.com/960x540/000/0f0 960w, https://dummyimage.com/1920x1080/000/0f0 1920w">
    <img style="width: 100%; max-width: 960px; height: auto;" src="https://dummyimage.com/480x270/000/0f0" width="960" height="540" alt="">
</picture>
```

However, it always returns the largest image it can find on mobile (yes, when ensuring the first image's resolution is set to at least the device's resolution), so that isn't an option.

Comment: Can you show what your current code looks like for the image?

Comment: @sean I've included an example now.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've thought about this a bit and, as of 2019, it doesn't seem that there is a proper way of doing this in CSS. Media queries are a possibility, but only viewport size (in CSS pixels) and pixel density can be obtained - not the native resolution - so there would be an unreasonable number of combinations to account for.

I'll include a bit of a messy example that any others will be able to work from, myself included. It only has these two resolutions, but you could always add more sizes to account for common horizontal resolutions such as 720px, 1080px and 1440px.

```
<picture>
    <noscript>
        <source type="image/webp" sizes="(min-width: 960px) 960px, 100vw" srcset="https://dummyimage.com/960x540/000/fff">
        <img style="width: 100%; max-width: 960px; height: auto;" src="https://dummyimage.com/960x540/000/fff" width="960" height="540" alt="">
    </noscript>
    <script>
        document.write('<source id="myImage" type="image/webp" sizes="(min-width: 960px) 960px, 100vw" srcset="https://spacergif.org/spacer.gif"><img style="width: 100%; max-width: 960px; height: auto;" src="https://dummyimage.com/960x540/000/fff" width="960" height="540" alt="">');

        var screenWidth = window.screen.availWidth * window.devicePixelRatio;
        var imageWidth;

        if (screenWidth <= 1080) {
            imageWidth = 960;
        } else {
            imageWidth = 1920;
        }

        document.getElementById("myImage").srcset = "https://dummyimage.com/" + imageWidth + "x" + imageWidth * 0.5625 + "/000/fff";
    </script>
</picture>
```

First we have the no-JS fallback, which is always 960px wide. Then JavaScript writes much the same thing to ensure no-JS users don't get it - alternatively you could probably just hide it from no-JS users with `<noscript>`ed CSS - but with spacer GIFs as the sources. You may want to use a base64 spacer GIF to save an HTTP request. And then the sources get replaced with either 960px or 1920px versions, depending on the native resolution of the webpage. Bear in mind this also includes space used by the developer tools in Chrome.